# why the first code report the desired result and the second not (Java beginner)

Tags: java

why the first code report the desired result and the second not (Java beginner)

```
public class p1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int[] a = new int[100];
        int i = 0 ;
        for(int element1 : a){
            element1 = i++;
            System.out.println(element1);
        }
    }
}
```

result 0,1,2,3,......,99
second version:-

```
public class p1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int[] a = new int[100];
    int i = 0 ;
    for(int element1 : a){
        element1 = i++;
    } 
    for(int element2 : a){
        System.out.println(element2);
    } 
}
```

}
result 0,0,0,0,.....,0

Comment: Because in the first code you set a value to `element1` before printing it.  In the second code you don't set any value to `element2`.  Can you describe why you were expecting a different result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: because OP is expecting the array content to change which does not happen in either case.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your code. These tips also help you inspect code to determine how it works.

Comment: Because you're iterating throw the array of zeros in the second case.

Comment: In the first example, add `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a))` after the for loop. You'll be surprised what it outputs.

Comment: does that mean that the array is still zeros in both cases

Answer (score 2):

It's because the array is not being updated:

```
for(int element1 : a){
    element1 = i;
    a[i++] = element1; //change array element's value to see the updated value
} 
for(int element2 : a){
    System.out.println(element2);
}
```

This is applicable to both code snippets (neither is updating the array).

*Just a side note*: A for-loop makes more sense in this case case (rather than the for-each).:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    a[i] = i; 
}
```

Comment: The first for loop would be more appropriately implemented using the traditional syntax: `for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I was just editing to add a note about that... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it seems like you're assuming that changing `element1` will modify the value in the array. That's actually not the case. What actually happens is that `element1` contains the *same value* as the corresponding value in the array - in a sense, it's a "copy" of it. Thus, when you set `element1`, all you're doing is setting `element1`, *not* the corresponding value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You did not assign a number to the array. In the first example it does not matter, because you are printing `element1`, which you just assign to a certain number. But not in the second example.

Comment: This looks to be a comment if I'm honest and in fact there is already a comment to this effect on the question.